# Mesibo On-premise app token authentication error

Tags: mesibo

We are getting below error when trying to start docker image using On-Premise server. Ports already opened (5222) outgoing and 5222,5228,4443,5443,513 (Incoming).

The Server has public IP and reachable to Internet.

### Below error code displayed.

E0109-072342-255 (12): Authenticating app token...
E0109-072342-255 (12): create_tcp_socket: unable to resolve onp-auth.mesibo.com
E0109-072342-255 (12): ======================= ERROR =======================

==> onp: Unable to verify app token. Ensure that your firewall does not block connection to onp-auth.mesibo.com

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you logged in to the shell and checked connectivity? Refer to the troubleshooting guide to learn how to access the shell.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/on-premise/#troubleshooting--faq

For example,

```
$ sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -v /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mesibo.example.com:/certs --net=host -v /etc/mesibo:/etc/mesibo mesibo/mesibo
```

also, make sure that `--net=host` is passed when running mesibo on-premise image

Comment: Thanks,  It worked --net=host was the option.